# Enable software cursor in x11

Tags: linux, debian, mouse, xorg, cursor

I am using XVFB to create a virtual screen buffer on my headless virtual machine. I noticed that XVFB is not by default rendering a mouse so I am trying to enable a software rendered mouse to get the mouse to show up in the screen buffer. I am having trouble enabling it.

Here is my Xorg.0.log: https://pastebin.com/xjKebjs7

I have also put the following files in the these places:

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-video.conf

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "My Graphics Card3"
        Driver          "fbdev"
        Option          "SWcursor"      "on"
EndSection
```

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-video.conf

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "My Graphics Card2"
        Driver          "fbdev"
        Option          "SWcursor"      "on"
EndSection
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact configuration, but `Xvfb` uses a **virtual** (invisible) framebuffer which you can't see unless you do a "screen"shot of the framebuffer, or use VNC to display the framebuffer, etc. You didn't mention any of this, so I not sure you are actually using `Xvfb` at all. Your log looks like a normal `X` server log which uses the framebuffer driver `fbdev`, which is a completely different thing. I am not even sure if `SWCursor` applies to `fbdev`, but if it does, try to spell it with a captial `C` and see if that works.